# Thymeleaf can't view anything except one page

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, controller, thymeleaf

All I can is viewing index.html, but when I am trying to surf to adminLogin for example all i see is:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

here is PortfolioApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PortfolioApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortfolioApplication.class, args);
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getMainPage() {
        return "index.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/adminLogin")
    public String getAboutPage() {
        return "adminLogin.html";
    }

}
```

when i am trying to call another pages from index.html nothing happens:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hotel_Management_java_project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="home" id="home">
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <h2>TourAgency</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="header_content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
                <div class="login">
                    <button class="loginbtn" id="loginbtn">Вход</button>
                    <div class="Login_content">
                        <a th:href="@{/adminLogin}">Вход для админа</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/employeelogin}">Вход для работника</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/userlogin}">Вход для пользователя</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository urepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index"; 
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/userlogin")
    public String index1(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "userlogin";
    }
```

I was trying change @Controller to @RestController, putting my main class to up and so on, but i've got no result

Comment: What about your spring security configuration details? Namely request authorizations? Could you please post additional logs such as stack trace.

Comment: With Thymeleaf, you need to use `@Controller`, not `@RestController`. The returned String should use the name of the Thymeleaf template, but _without_ the `.html` extension. So use `return "adminLogin"`, not `return "adminLogin.html"`.